# Maximize interaction between people

Tags: algorithm, optimization

There is a round table. And there are n people, some of them are friends with each other.
A person sitting on table can interact with the person adjacent to him if he's a friend.

We have to find an algorithm to arrange the n people on table so as to maximize the total interaction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem can be reduced to the [Travelling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem).

Consider each person as a node in a [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29). The cost of moving between friends is 0, and between non-friends is 1. The task is now to find a [Hamiltonian cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_cycle) with the least cost. This is an [NP-hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard) problem.

A [greedy algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) is to place the person with the least friends first, then try to place two of his friends next to him (if he has more than two friends, choose those two friends who themselves have least friends). Keep going in this manner, placing friends next to friends if possible, until everyone is placed. This won't guarantee finding the optimal solution, but it will be very fast to compute.

Comment: It's a little bit different, now that I've come to think about it.

Comment: -1 It's longest path not TSP, Also if you want to say something at least should say Hamiltonian Path not TSP, TSP is definable in complete graph.

Answer (score 3):

Mark, "equivalent" means that you've given a reduction from problem A to problem B *and* a reduction from problem B to problem A. You've reduced this problem to (non-metric) TSP, which tells us that TSP is at least as hard as this problem.

All people can be seated simultaneously next to friends if and only if the friend graph has a Hamilton cycle, so this problem is in fact NP-hard.

Mark's reduction means that we can use the O(n<sup>2</sup> 2<sup>n</sup>)-time dynamic program for TSP to solve this problem. Let x be the oldest person at the table. The DP computes, for each nonempty set S of people not including x and each possible person y in S, the best solution where the people in S - {y} are sitting in the counterclockwise arc from x to y.

Answer (score 1):

We could use arches to represent friendship and the problem of maximising interaction can be substituted by the problem of finding a closed path in the graph, touching all persons. All arches have the same weight, for instance 1.

If it's not possible, we've to find the path touching the maximum number of persons and then start over with the remaining persons.